# Get image when press a cell in tableView popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller

I try to comprehend iOS dev. and have a question...here...
    I have a simple scrollview gallery with pageControl(array of images) and have a custom button which show popover with tableView and names of images. I want following...When press some cell with name of image, return to scrollview gallery on image which i need...
    Thanks for help and answers..

```
Code of ScrollView and PageControl:

-(void)scrollViewMethod {

    for(UIView* view in [scrollView subviews])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < [imgArray count]; i++) {

        //Create objects in pages
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        self.imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        self.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        self.imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imgView];

    }

}


-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    //self.pageControl.numberOfPages
    // Disable vertical scroll
    [sender setContentOffset:CGPointMake(sender.contentOffset.x, scrollY)];
}

And Code of custom button and popover:

-(IBAction)showTable:(id)sender {

    UIImage *btnTableImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"];

    UIButton *bttn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    bttn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, btnTableImage.size.width, btnTableImage.size.height );

    [bttn addTarget:self action:@selector(showTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [bttn setImage:btnTableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonListItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bttn];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:buttonListItem];


    if (self._popover) {
        [self._popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self._popover = nil;
        return;
    }
    SelectImageTableController *sitc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectImageTableController"];
    sitc.delegate = self;
    self._popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:sitc];
    self._popover.delegate = self;
    [self._popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:buttonListItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

And tableView:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imgList count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [imgList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[ivc.imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //ImageViewController *ivc = [[ImageViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"row: %d %@", indexPath.row, cell.textLabel.text);
}
```

Comment: What u shown in cell of table view?? image name?? And where all the images are saved in document folder or in Bundle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have indexPath of selected cell. X coordinate of each image equals to self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i. So You can use [self.scrollView scrollToRect:rect animated:NO] where Your

```
i = indexPath.row;
rect.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
```

Put it in didSelect method of tableviewdelegate.

Comment: Maybe, i bad explained, i have 2 controllers...FirstController - ScrollView, array of images, popover init etc...SecondController - tableView content of popover which consist of array of only image names...I understand your answer so...In scrollViewMethod i put [self.scrollView scrollToRect:rect...........:NO]; And in didSelectRow i put the i = indexPath.row etc...?

Comment: If You have 2 controllers try to use delegate pattern. I mean when You select cell You call method of delegate which should scroll to appropriate image

Comment: "He" says thank to you). I started doing by delegate, but this is the question. How do this. I'm trying struggling with pageControl but it only set a page, scrollview remains in place. I'm trying with 'svrushal's' advice. But image stands in end of gallery and also duplicates. How make this perfect? Without strong hammering...

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood that in table view cell you have image name and on click on cell you have to show that image.

Now you haven't mention where that images are saved but still will try to give answer. I hope you will get some idea to you.

First create name of image.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cName= [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@.png",cell.textLabel.text];
```

I have considered here png as an extension of image.

1.If images are saved in Document folder then

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:cName];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
```

2.If images are saved in Bundle i.e in resources folder of application

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:cell.textLabel.text ofType:@"png"]];
```

Now img will be the image which u can use to set your imageview image.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but how a cell understand which image need to return?

Comment: No, i explained below answer

Comment: In that you are saying you have array of image name then what is the problem. Using that u can get the image from specified path. Just tell me where that images are saved? I have explained all the possibilities

Comment: how i get image by path when all images in another array in scrollView? image locate in resources of inside application

Comment: check option 2 for that in my answer..use cell.textLabel.text as image name

Comment: Okey, I declare NSString *cName = [.....]; and UIImage *img = [...] in didSelectRow? And how they operate?

Comment: Yes you have to did it in didselect row. so that from then u will get the image name. Then by creating the path of the image you can retrieve that image in img variable then use that img wherever you want

Comment: Seems You don't understand question. HeOrShe wants show already placed image instead of path for image. Also HeOrShe already have array of images and can retrieve any of them.

Comment: "He" says thank to you). I started doing by delegate, but this is the question. How do this. I'm trying struggling with pageControl but it only set a page, scrollview remains in place. I'm trying with 'svrushal's' advice. But image stands in end of gallery and also duplicates. How make this perfect? Without strong hammering...